# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. More than 1 value was returned.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Iam trying this query and i get these following errors. I also get an error saying that the primary key constraint PK_ITEMPATH has been violated. What should i do inorder to rectify this error as the query wont be able to run successfully

```
USE Sk_EN_UserDB
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF 
GO
IF(DB_NAME() NOT LIKE '%_UserDB')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('You must run this script in UserDB database',18,0)
    SET NOEXEC ON
END

GO

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserRights.Path WHERE PathID = 'Myviews'))
BEGIN
    insert into UserRights.Path(PathID, IsVendorSpecific)
    values('Myviews', 0)
END


IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserRights.Products WHERE ProjectName = 'Products'))
BEGIN
    insert into UserRights.Products(ProductID, ProjectName)
    values(
        (select MAX(ProductID) + 1 from [UserRights].Products),
        'Products'
    )
END

insert into UserRights.ProductsToPath(ProductID, PathID)
values(
    (select ProductID
    from [UserRights].Products
    where ProjectName = 'Products'),
    'Myviews'
)

insert into UserRights.ModulesToProducts(ModuleID, ProductID)
values(
    (select ModuleID
    from [UserRights].[Modules]
    where DisplayName = 'Products Product' or HierarchyName like '%Products Product%'), 
    (select ProductID
    from [UserRights].Products
    where ProjectName = 'Products')
)
```

Comment: `What should i do` - make sure the subqueries you are using in `values` return one value each.

Comment: One of your SELECT queries returns more than one record. Consider using LIMIT/TOP 1.

Comment: One question per question. Also, are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @PawełDyl, using TOP/LIMIT here may avoid the error, but will OP get the correct result?

Comment: @jarlh Using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your inner selects are probably returning more than 1 value per INSERT statement.

Try changing your INSERT statements from:

```
insert into UserRights.ProductsToPath(ProductID, PathID)
values(
    (select ProductID
    from [UserRights].Products
    where ProjectName = 'Products'),
    'Myviews'
)
```

to:

```
insert into UserRights.ProductsToPath(ProductID, PathID)
(select TOP 1 ProductID
    from [UserRights].Products
    where ProjectName = 'Products'),
    'Myviews'
```

If you need to do batch inserts (more than 1 record per statement), [use a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311319/how-to-insert-value-to-table-using-cursor-in-stored-procedure-without-getting-du).

With regards to the ITEMPATH PK Violation - your question doesn't give me enough information about your table schema, but the error means that you're probably inserting a record with a primary key that already exists. Most likely to do with your inner selects as well.

Comment: @drminnar,  the erros dont come any more however i get an error of `Incorrect syntax near ','.` when i change it to that.